# How do I diff incoming changesets with Beyond Compare 4 and hg?

Tags: mercurial, beyondcompare4

I have been using the mercurial and Beyond Compare 4 tools together for about 2 weeks now and feel fairly confident in my usage, however I still seem to have a problem when comparing incoming changesets against my current local codebase. The problem is emphasized when I attempting a complicated merge.

> Just to clarify, I am avoiding the use of tools such as TortoiseHg,
>   although I do have it installed. I am searching for feedback via cmd line operations only.

My current templated method to pull down the incoming changesets via the following ( as an [alias] )

```
hg in --verbose -T "\nchangeset: \t{rev}\nbranch: \t{branch}\nuser: \t\t{author}\ndate: \t\t{date(date,'%m-%d-%Y %I:%M%p')}\ndescription: \n\t{desc|fill76|tabindent}\n\n{files % ' \t{file}\n'}\n----------\n"
```

As an example, here is a simplified (and cleverly abstracted) block returned ::

```
changeset:      4685
branch:         Feature-WI209825
user:           Jack Handy <jhandy@anon.com>
date:           01-19-2015 10:19AM
description:
        Display monkey swinging from vines while whistling dixie

        Zoo/MonkeyCage/Resources/Localization.Designer.cs
        Zoo/MonkeyCage/Resources/Localization.resx
        Zoo/MonkeyCage/Utility/Extensions.cs
```

If I were to be comparing changes locally, I would simply use the following command ::

```
hg bcomp -r 4685 -r default <optional file name>
```

and then I would get an instance of Beyond Compare with a folder structure and files and I could just navigate accordingly to view the changes...however, when I attempt to do this with a changeset that has yet to be pulled into my local repository, I can't.

How do I diff incoming changesets with my local repository?

**---- UPDATE --------------------------------**

I pursued the idea of bundling the incoming changes and then trying to use BC4 to diff the bundle to any given branch/revision on my local repo.

```
hg in --bundle "C:\Sandboxes\Temp\temp.hg"
```

This creates a compressed file archive containing all the new changes.

Now I simply need to diff this bundle with my local, however am having difficulty optimizing this. Currently, I am using variations on the following command:

```
hg -R "C:\Sandboxes\Temp\temp.hg" bcomp -r default
```

Alas, I am still having difficulty perfecting this...any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you can, since your local repository doesn't yet have that changeset, so mercurial can't create a local copy of the revision, as it doesn't have visibility of what the change actually is.

The `-p` flag to `hg incoming` will show you the patch for each revision, but that isn't what you want.

Why not just `pull` the remote changes anyway? It wont hurt unless you actually `update`. You can then do your diff in the normal way.

Comment: True, however with tools such as Tortoise Hg Workbench, you're able to diff the incoming packages before an official pull, which is my happy path when I have the choice. I did look into the ability to create a bundle and then diff the bundle against the local repository...which opens up many options.

Answer (score -1):

`hg diff` is a local operation. 
But you can simply call `hg incoming -p` in order to obtain a diff view of what you're going to pull. See `hg help incoming` for more options and refinement (e.g. if you need to diff against a specific rev etc)

Comment: did you not read the question? the first example I show is using hg (in)coming

Comment: You were asking for a diff with your local repo. The flag "-p" used on incoming provides you with that... and you did not imply that you were aware of it.

Comment: did you even both to run the line I presented? you'd find it's much more informative than -p offers...which is a convoluted mash of monkey poo in a cmd window...the question is how to take this info and put it somewhere useful...which is why I also refer to Beyond Compare...